# ToolbarAndroid is not displaying in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning `react-native` programming, creating toolbar using this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html but in my case it is not being showed. I could not understand what exactly mistake I am doing.

Can anyone help me for this.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { AppRegistry, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ToolbarAndroid } from 'react-native';
 import { ToolBar } from 'react-native-material-design';

 class LoginComponent extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', margin:10}}>

            <ToolbarAndroid title="Login" titleColor="black"/>

            <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth: .5}}
                placeholder="Email address" underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>

            <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth: .5}}
                placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true} underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>

            <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 10 , backgroundColor: '#2E8B57'}}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>LOG IN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }

 AppRegistry.registerComponent('Myntra', () => LoginComponent);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5293). A workaround is set a height for your ToolbarAndroid.

Comment: Thanks. I have set the height also however it is still not showing. Please see updated code http://pastebin.com/XhU17Xe5

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo error, but your Toolbar style is set as `style={styles.styles}`. I think it should be `style={styles.toolbar}`. If it doesn't work, can you try to set the `height` property for the Toolbar?

Answer (score 2):

As im new to react-native, this is the best solution i found so far, hope it helps.
https://github.com/react-native-community/toolbar-android

First,
add `npm install @react-native-community/toolbar-android --save`
or 
yarn lover add `yarn add @react-native-community/toolbar-android`

Second, Run `react-native start` command.

Third, Run `react-native run-android`

Happy coding :)